# Check if time is in a certain range

Tags: php, datetime

I am using `php 7.4` and I am creating a function that should check certain conditions, such as:

- Check if *xx* Minutes - `$timeToLastPostinMinutes` - have been passed until the schedule process can start
- Is today a day which is allowed
- Is today a time slot which is in the allowed range
- If all conditions are met, then return a `Datetime` with *xx* Minutes added

I created the following function which should check the two conditions above:

```
<?php

/**
 * Weekdays: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
 * Times are as an array specified, from-to: [["09:00", "11:00"], ["18:00", "24:00"]],
 * TimeTolastPost example 15 for 15 minutes
 * @param Datetime $lastPostdateTime
 * @param $weekdays
 * @param $times
 * @param $timeToLastPostinMinutes
 * @throws Exception
 */
function createPostSchedule(Datetime $lastPostdateTime, $allowedWeekdays, $allowedTimes, $timeToLastPostinMinutes, $timeToWaitInMin)
{
    $today = new DateTime();

    // if $lastPostdateTime is x Minutes ($timeToWaitInMin) in the past, then start the schedule process
    if ($lastPostdateTime->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $timeToWaitInMin . 'M'))->getTimestamp() > $today->getTimestamp()) {
        $today->format('N');
        // check if today is in the day array
        if(in_array(intval($today->format('N')), $allowedWeekdays)) {
            // check if time is in the slot
            foreach ($allowedTimes as $key => $val) {
                if (strtotime($val[0]) > $today->getTimestamp() && strtotime($val[1]) < $today->getTimestamp()) {
                    if($timeToLastPostinMinutes != 0) {
                        return $lastPostdateTime->add(new DateInterval('PT' . $timeToLastPostinMinutes . 'M'));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y H:i:s', '10-16-2020 15:55:33');

$postSchedule = createPostSchedule($dateTime, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [["09:00", "24:00"]], 15, 1440);

echo $postSchedule->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

However, I get `null` back.

I think there might be a problem in comparing the time slots. However, they are comparing two timestamps to each other, which seems right?

Any suggestions why I get `null` back?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing both the start and end of each time-slot to the same value - current timestamp. It is quite obvious that it is not possible for the current timestamp to be below the time-slot start and above the time-slot end simultaneously. You need to reverse the comparison:

```php
if (strtotime($val[0]) < $today->getTimestamp() && strtotime($val[1]) > $today->getTimestamp())
```